# Passing null for a short?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following method:

```
    //returns -1 on failure
    public static int Add(
        string name, string email, string password, short defaultNumWeek)
    {
        KezberPMDBDataContext db = new KezberPMDBDataContext();
        Employee employee = new Employee 
        { 
            EmployeName = name,
            EmployeEmail = email,
            EmployePassword = password,
            DefaultNumWeek = defaultNumWeek
        };
        db.Employees.InsertOnSubmit(employee);
        try
        {
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        return employee.EmployeID;
    }
```

The last parameter is optional and can be null in the database. How can I do this without creating 2 separate methods? I have other ones that are less simple. How can I pass a base type as null?

Comment: Reference for answers below: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: FYI: that try/catch is a very bad practice. When you get a -1 from this method, you'll have no idea what the problem was. Just remove the try/catch entirely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `Nullable` type as

```
public static int Add(
        string name, string email, string password, short? defaultNumWeek)
```

`DefaultNumWeek` property of `Employee` mast be `Nullable` too.

Comment: Depending on the version of .NET, this can be expanded to have `defaultNumWeek` be an optional parameter, allowing the user to either pass null *or* pass nothing.

Answer (score 3):

```
static void Bar(Nullable<short> s)
{

}
```

or

```
static void Bar(short? s)
{

}
```

The former is merely a short hand, see [Using Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Change the definition to:

```
public static int Add(
        string name, string email, string password, short? defaultNumWeek = null)
```

This allows you to call the same function while omitting the `defaultNumWeek` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass it and don't use it if it's null.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this with [Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1t3y8s4s.aspx). C# has an alias where you attach a question mark (?) to a struct type (like short).

This allows you to compare it against null, ask whether it has a value and so forth.